# Symfony best practise: Where to place these constants?

Tags: symfony, oop, model-view-controller, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm wondering, where I should place constants, e.g. for mapping a status, in Symfony. I'm used to set them in a controller, but it doesn't feel right and I prefer the entity, but not really.

**What's right?**

It's not a "what do you think?"-Question, I really want to know the **best-practise** and appreciate explanation or linked source(s). Both work, for now.

**Controller** or

```
namespace my\bundle\Controller;

class MyController {
    const STATUS_NEW     = 1;
    const STATUs_PENDING = 2;
    // ...
}
```

**Entity** ?

```
namespace my\bundle\Entity;

class MyEntity {
    const STATUS_NEW     = 1;
    const STATUs_PENDING = 2;
    // ...
}
```

Example in twig:

```
{% set statusNew = constant('my\\bundle\\Controller\\MyController::STATUS_NEW')%} {# or \\Entity\\ #}
{% if data.status == statusNew %}
    Hi, I'm new.
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance!

M.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO the entity itself is a good place. For the twig approach, in my previous project, I create some helper method on the entity for check the status like :

```
namespace my\bundle\Entity;

class MyEntity {
    const STATUS_NEW     = 1;
    const STATUs_PENDING = 2;
    // ...

   // For each const status
   public function isNew(){
     return $this->status == self::STATUS_NEW;
   }
}
```

and use in the twig like:

```
{% if data.isNew %}{# more contract form: if data.new  #}
    Hi, I'm new.
{% endif %}
```

And you don't expose the status field outside the entity (incapsulate the logic of new).

Hope this help.

Comment: Or in the interface and then referenced with `self::MY_CONSTANT` if you are using them. That way the constant isn't tied directly to that specific class but to the expected usage instead.

Comment: This seems to be the appropriate solution, however, like Qoop said, you should use `self::STATUS_NEW` instead. Also, `getIsNew` is a terrible function naming. You should call them `isNew` and `isPending`. In twig, you can call it directly with `{% if data.new %}`

Comment: of course, thanks to @Qoop for clarification about constant usage and to Touki for the mistake in the method name. I update my answer

Comment: of course, thanks to Qoop for clarification about constant usage and to @Touki for the mistake in the method name. I update my answer

Answer (score 3):

The answer is it depends, but there are now Symfony best practices; in particular there [is a section on constants vs. configuration options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options) that speaks to exactly what you're asking.

> Use constants to define configuration options that rarely change.

The nice thing about defining constants in classes is that you can easily access them in Twig.  For instance, if you have a `Post` class like the example in the best practices, and pass an instance of that as `post` to your template, you can access the constant via:

```
{{ constant('NUM_ITEMS', post) }}
```

Now, there are definitely times where you might want to specify configurable options - say if you're creating a reusable bundle and want to allow an override of these values.  So again it depends, but for your case, Symfony recommends placing them in your entity.

Answer (score 2):

The STATUS constants belong in the entity so that they can be reused in multiple contexts (multiple controllers, for example) without needing to redefine the constants in each controller.